# CSS Sprite - thin white lines at edge

Tags: css, css-sprites

I've created a toolbar using 14px x 14px images stored in a sprite. When displayed, the image has a very clear thin white edge on the top and right sides (you may have to zoom in to see it - it's no more than 1px). For the life of me, I don't have any idea how to get rid of it. I've tried moving the offset 1px in any direction - which clearly shows it's positioned correctly. Changing margin and padding don't fix it. Any ideas how to get rid of the white lines and what is causing it to render this way?

```css
button.video-sprite-popout {
        background: url("https://www.mseifert.com/img-common/video-controls-sprite.png") no-repeat -56px -14px scroll;
        border: 0 !important;
        height: 14px;
        margin-left: 8px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: 14px;
    }

    .video-controls {
        background-color: black;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class='video-controls'>
  <div><button class='video-sprite-popout'></div>
<div>
```

Comment: Answer by @Jae does the trick. Or recreate your sprite file with more spacing around the icons if you need the anti-aliassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely due to antialiasing, and it is very device/browser specific. The lines you are seeing are subpixels. Though I am not able to see this specific problem on my device, you can use either of these on your background image container. See which one fits better.

```
button.video-sprite-popout {
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}

button.video-sprite-popout {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Either setting fixes it for most zoom levels. They seem to do the same thing in terms of the result. Yes, they are "subpixels", although I didn't know the term. I really need to look into learning vector graphics... Thanks for the response.

Comment: Great to hear! Please tag the answer as accepted if it worked out for you.

Comment: Will do. Just waiting to see if there are any other solutions which work at all zoom levels.